# SQL with 2 INNER JOIN's on the same column not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am trying to use the following code to get the 6 users with which the current user has most recently chatted. I have two problems. First of all, if the current user has recieved a message from the other user but has only sent, that other user isnt fetched. Second of all, the ORDER BY clause is causing an error. Im a beginner in SQL so I have no idea what's going on. 
Thanks in Advance!

Here's the code:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users INNER JOIN
    messages fromuser 
    ON (fromuser.fromid = users.id) INNER JOIN
    messages touser 
    ON (touser.toid = users.id)
WHERE fromuser.toid = :userid OR touser.fromid = :meid
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY MAX(messages.datetime)
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Do you really have two parameters, `:meid` and `:userid`?

Comment: `but has only sent, that other user isnt fetched` what does this mean?

Comment: I mean that if a user has sent a message to another person but hasnt received a message back, this sql statement doesnt get that user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do your job, and it relies less on MySQL extensions than your other answer so far.  I estimate that it would perform about the same, but it's surely wordier.

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT otherid
  FROM (
    SELECT
       m.fromid AS otherid,
       MAX(m.datetime) as maxts
    FROM messages m
    WHERE m.toid = :userid
    GROUP BY m.fromid

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      m.toid AS otherid,
      MAX(m.datetime) as maxts
    FROM messages m
    WHERE m.fromid = :userid
    GROUP BY m.toid
  ) um
  ORDER BY maxts DESC
  LIMIT 6
) otheru
INNER JOIN users u
  ON u.id = otheru.otherid
```

Comment: I tried it but I get the following error "Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias'".

Comment: Ok, I gave the inner subquery an alias.  (Actually, moved the outer subquery's alias to the inner one, and gave the outer one a new alias).

Comment: It worked! I mean it still wont show a user if that user hasnt messaged me but still! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is doomed to fail, because one `users.id` cannot be two different values at the same time.  I think this query does what you want:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM messages m INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON (m.fromid = u.id AND m.toid = :userid) OR
        (m.toid = u.id AND m.fromid = :userid )
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY MAX(m.datetime) DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

Notice that it joins to the `users` table by the `id` that is not the current user.

Comment: still get an error. Unknown column 'messages.datetime' in 'order clause

Comment: @TheSabby . . . I fixed that already.  I replaced the table names with shorter table aliases, and missed that particular reference.

Comment: Yeah thanks but it still doesnt order them correctly (most recent user first) and I still dont get users that I've sent messages to but havent sent back

Comment: I just did some testing and figured out that it's ordering them not according to the time of the last sent message but rather the time the users were created

Comment: @TheSabby . . . The `order by` is for the most recent message (`m.datetime`).  That should have nothing to do with the creation time of the user.

Comment: I know but that's just how it behaves

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the results.  They appear to be ordered by user creation date because you are going in *increasing* order of latest message date, and of course the earliest users have the earliest messages.  You want `ORDER BY MAX(m.datetime) DESC`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger . . . That makes so much sense that I added it into the answer.  However, I note that the question is pretty explicit about the ordering.